# Is it possible to check sqlite values without a cursor? - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to stop the user from entering the same string value for the "title" field in an appointment creation app in a calendar, as homework.

Here is what I thought of so far:

```
private static String[] CHECK = {TITLE};
    private Cursor addAppointment(String title, String time, String details){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = calendarData.getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = calendarData.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DATE, calendar.getDate());
        values.put(TITLE, title);
        values.put(TIME, time);     
        values.put(DETAILS, details);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Cursor titleCursor = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, CHECK, TITLE+" = "+appointmentTitle.getText().toString(), null, null, null, null);
        if(titleCursor.getString(0) != null){//MEANING THERE IS A DUPLICATE
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setMessage("You've entered a duplicate title field, please rename.");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   alertDialog.dismiss();

                } });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        return titleCursor;
    }
```

But I don't like the idea of having everything in my addAppointments method, I'd rather leave it clean and simple.

I tried doing the following as an alternative:

```
private static String[] CHECK = {TITLE};
    private void addAppointment(String title, String time, String details){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = calendarData.getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = calendarData.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DATE, calendar.getDate());
        values.put(TITLE, title);
        values.put(TIME, time);     
        values.put(DETAILS, details);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    private Cursor checkTitle(){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = calendarData.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor titleCursor = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, CHECK, TITLE+" = "+appointmentTitle.getText().toString(), null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(titleCursor);
        return titleCursor;
    }

    private void showTitleError(Cursor cursor){
        if(cursor.getString(0) != null){//MEANING THERE IS A DUPLICATE
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setMessage("You've entered a duplicate title field, please rename.");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   alertDialog.dismiss();

                } });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

but I get this error in both cases: 04-24 17:56:51.263: E/AndroidRuntime(17856): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: hello: , while compiling: SELECT title FROM appointments WHERE title = hello

Please if you have any advice please share, thank you.

Comment: *Read* the error message closely. Note how it has *nothing* to do with the title. -1 (for lack of problem/issue refinement and grossly incorrect title) and a "too localized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `appointmentTitle.getText().toString()` in single quotes:

```
db1.query(TABLE_NAME, CHECK, TITLE+" = '"+appointmentTitle.getText().toString() + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

That way your assembled query looks like:

```
SELECT title FROM appointments WHERE title = 'hello'
```

As other posters have **courteously** noted, however, this can cause an SQL injection issue if your query here takes User input.  Adapting to a parameterized approach is the better way.

Comment: Did Android *really* re-introduce SQL Injection? I am impressed... but not by this answer (-1 [see the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for a better way).

Comment: @pst Well better obviously is to parameterize the query instead - but as for why it was breaking. I would also say that android helps you avoid SQL injection, but it doesn't make you

Comment: Is this the right way to check if the value in the database and the one entered by the user are the same? if(cursor != null)? Because every time I try to add a new title it gives me the alert dialog which is not suppose to happen

Comment: @AZ1 I would check the number of rows returned instead:
`if(cursor.getCount > 0)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want it injection safe use it that way

```
Cursor titleCursor = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, CHECK, TITLE+" = ?",
        new String[]{ appointmentTitle.getText().toString() }, null, null, null);
```

the `?` is replaced by `'`-quoted and escaped data from the next argument.

Hint: if you want to enforce a unique title, then make the database column `UNIQUE`. That way you will get an `SQLiteException` when you `insert` data that has a title that is already present. Instead of an expection you could also make the column `UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE` which means that it simply does not insert the data and does not throw an error.

Comment: that makes sense, I will look into making the column unique, that way I don't have to implement an alert dialog as it will stop the user completely from entering the same title. thanks